# Can´t compare strings

Tags: c++

i'm a beginner and i'm trying to get input for "item" in the calculate() function and see if it matches with one from the vector "lista" (get_value() function), i have tried a lot but even if those 2 strings look the same it always turns out that they are not equal. I have also tried compare() and i get -1 value with "item.compare(lista[0].name)" eventhough i am sure that those two strings should be equal :(

Here is the code

```
class insumos
{
public:
    std::string name;
    double value;
    insumos(std::string x, double y) : name(x), value(y) {};
    

};
// vector para almacenar la lista de insumos y precios por gramo
std::vector<insumos> lista;

void push_insumos()
{
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "aceite de almendras", 0.19 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "aceite de argan", 0.44 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "aceite de jojoba", 0.36 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "aceite de coco", 0.056 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "karite", 0.055 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "aceite de palta", 0.19 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "aceite de germen de trigo", 0.26 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "aceite de girasol", 0.16 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "aceite de oliva", 0.027 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "agua destilada", 0.007 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "soda caustica",0.023 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de tomillo", 1.06 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de limon", 0.5 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de naranja", 0.39 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de basil", 1.05 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de gene", 1.5 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de geranio", 1.08 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de incienso", 2.6 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de citro", 0.87 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de romero", 0.76 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de ylang ylang", 1.66 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de cart", 1.16 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "esencial de lavanda", 0.98 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "vitamina e", 0.83 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "madder root", 0.14 });
    lista.push_back(insumos{ "hierbas", 0.005 });

}
//

double get_value(std::string s, double x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (s == lista[i].name) return lista[i].value * x;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("error");
}


double calculate()
{   
    try
    {
        double resultado = 0;
        double gramos;
        std::string item;
        std::cout << "Hola! cuantos insumos en total utilizaste para esta receta?\n";
        int cant_de_veces;
        std::cin >> cant_de_veces;
        std::cout << "Porfavor ingresa la siguiente informacion para calcular el precio\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < cant_de_veces; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << " Insumo: "; getline(std::cin, item,'.');
            std::cout << " gramos: "; std::cin >> gramos;
            resultado += get_value(item, gramos);
                              
        }
        return resultado;
        
    }
    
    
    catch (std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: The shown code uses `>>` and `std::getline` in a way that's almost certainly wrong, and if you show the values that you think are getting read in, you will see the problem. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: i've seen the output from std::getline and it shows e.g "aceite de almendras", but when i try the statement "item == lista[0].name" they are not equal